# DB2Driver from jar dependency not found

Tags: java, gradle, db2

I have created a small jar distribution that sets up a database connection for me.
Problem is that when i add it as a gradle dependency I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

Gradle dependecie tree:

```
--- prokasdb-connector:prokasDBConnection:2.0
     +--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
     +--- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4
     |    \--- commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.4
     +--- commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.4
     +--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
     +--- prokasdb-connector-dependencies:db2jcc:0.1
     +--- prokasdb-connector-dependencies:db2jcc4:0.1
     +--- prokasdb-connector-dependencies:db2jcc_license_cu:0.1
     \--- prokasdb-connector-dependencies:db2small:0.1
```

Another remark is that when I go to the build path via eclipse menu i noticed that the last for dependencies are missing, while the rest where added automatically. The db2 connector is contained within the last 4 jars, that is why java cannot find it

Comment: Where are you trying to connect? From a test case? Or from your gradle script? Under which configuration are you adding the driver?

Comment: I am trying to connect from within a java program. prokasdb-connector:prokasDBConnection:2.0 is a wrapper for my db connection.

Comment: How are you running the java program? I'm guessing the driver's not on the classpath as you are executing

Comment: Yes. The driver was not in the classpath. I added `compile ('prokasdb-connector:prokasDBConnection:2.0'){ force =  true changing = true }'` to my build.gradle. Now the dependencies are in the classpath.

Comment: This is the last time I try to help. HOW ARE YOU RUNNING THE JAVA PROGRAM???

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `build.gradle` and run `gradle findClass` from command line

```
task findClass {
    doLast {
        def foundJars = [] as Set
        configurations.runtime.files.each { jar ->
            zipTree(jar).visit { FileVisitDetails fvd ->
                def path = fvd.relativePath.pathString.replace('\\', '/')
                if (path == 'com/ibm/db2/jcc/DB2Driver.class') {
                   foundJars << jar
                }
            }
        }
        println "Found driver in ${foundJars}"
    }
}
```